# Is it grammatically correct to use 'In the present job' in this context?

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to use 'In the present job' in this context?

> In the present job, I carry out the regeneration and production of
>   machinery parts in the food sector.

Comment: This is OT proofreading, but I will add that “regeneration” does not seem like the right word here.

Comment: He may not have written this. He may simply have read it somewhere and it called his knowledge of English into question. It's a valid question and it merits an answer.

Comment: The specific source of concern was identified twice to be the phrase "in the present job." Compare umteen questions about [in the park vs at the park](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40439/should-i-say-she-is-in-the-park-or-she-is-at-the-park) or [In a job, at a job](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38148/in-a-job-at-a-job).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't incorrect, but it sounds extremely awkward. Normally we use possessive adjectives with "job" :

> In **my** present job, I carry out...

Answer (score -2):

I think it is better to use **current** instead of **present**

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! Could you please explain *why* you think it's better?