# In A Job, At A Job

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have a question about "in a job" [here](http://www.nytimes.com/projects/2013/police-domestic-abuse/):

> Mr. Feliciano remains employed by the department, working ***in a desk job*** after two domestic violence offenses and a violation of a court order to stay away from his wife.

How is "***in*** *a job*" different from "***at*** *a job*"?

Comment: I dunno.  I like [*"working **at** a desk job"*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=working+in+a+desk+job%2Cworking+at+a+desk+job&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10) better, though.

Comment: In this case, both mean the same. In and At do have rules, but

Comment: In this case, both mean the same. There are some rules for in and at, but the above is idiomatic.  I would have said "working at a desk job", or "working a desk job."  If the job word had been "construction", I might have said "I work in construction."  "Mr. F remains working in construction."  "Mr F remains employed, working in a construction job at the old mill."

Comment: I think there is a subtle difference in this context because "desk job" is a role, and not really a job in the same way that I might be "working at a clerical job". In this specific circumstance, I think "desk job" has a very particular meaning as "not on patrol". He remains employed working at a law enforcement job in a "desk jockey" role. I could be giving the reporter too much credit however.

Answer (score 1):

Using Verb + Preposition, **work in** would be the standard usage.

**Work at** is also permissible, but has the additional meaning for a specific place:

> She works at McDonald's.
>
> He works at the restaurant.
>
> (nb: "He works **at a** (non-specific) restaurant" has the same meaning as "He works **in a** restaurant")

Finally, **work at** carries the additional complication of being a phrasal verb:

> **work at** *[phrasal verb]*:
>   work at (something) : to make an effort to do (something) better
>
> *He needs to work at his handwriting.*
>
> *She has been working (harder) at controlling her temper.*

See: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/work

I myself prefer "work in" to "work at" in your example, probably to avoid ambiguity of him working to "improve his desk job", or working a desk job to improve himself.

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16813/which-one-is-right-he-works-at-company-x-or-in-company-x

These days you'll hear "She works in McDonald's", but that's a "no-no" :)