# Is it appropriate to use "in" always to denote inside a vehicle?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-usage

Normally when someone is inside a vehicle it is written as

```
He is in the car
I am in the bus
```

But can I use the same word when it is related with a bike or bicycle
are below sentences are correct ?

```
I am in the bicycle
He is in a bike
```

What is the correct way to express above two sentences ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless the bicycle or bike has a ceiling. This is because you use *in* with vehicles, such as a car or bus, that have a ceiling, so it can be said you are inside the car or inside the bus.

For a normal bicycle or bike, you sit *on* the seat, or you sit *on* the bicycle or bike.

For a long explanation of the uses of *in, on* and *at,* see my [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40439/should-i-say-she-is-in-the-park-or-she-is-at-the-park/40488#40488). It is detailed, but it has examples for vehicles. For instance, if you are a bus passenger, you would probably say you are *on* the bus. But I don't want to repeat here what I already typed in the answer I just linked to.

Comment: Actually, you get ON a bus. You also get on a train or a plane. You get ON a boat if the boat is over a certain size, or IN a boat if it's small.