# "There is" or "There are" when detailing things together: a theater, a cafe, and a shop?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural, existentials

Which one of the following is grammatically correct?

> a) There **is** a theater, a cafe, and a shop near the park center.
>
> b) There **are** a theater, a cafe, and a shop near the park center.

Comment: The question reminds me of a question about "[a cafe on the corner](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49181)".

Comment: @Jasper: Sometimes, such of those simple cases make me confused. So, we always use **there** to talk about what exists?

Comment: aida -- Sometimes "there" literally means "that place over there".  And sometimes "there" is a placeholder in a sentence about whether something exists.  Answers to this question might help other people who want to use "there is" or "there are" as a placeholder about whether thing(s) exist, so I added the "existentials" tag.

Comment: @Jasper: I only could up vote you if my reputation score has surpassed the limit :), thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The first one.

It's like repeating *there is* on every comma.

> There is a theater, *there is* a cafe, and *there is* a shop near the park centre.

If you want to use *are,* you need the plural for each noun.

> There are theaters, cafes, and shops near the park centre.

Comment: Sometimes, such of those simple cases make me confused. So, we always use **there** to talk about what exists?

Comment: Yes. *There is/are* for singular or plural things.

Comment: am thanking you. Unfortunately, I can't up vote due to my low reputation score.

Answer (score 0):

This is [a rule of thumb](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rule-of-thumb):

1. When talking about **more than one thing**, then you have to use "**there are**".
2. When talking about **one thing only**, then you have to use "**there is**".
3. When taling about uncountable things ([mass noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun)) such as water, money, sky etc. normally is used to refer them as a singular. (there is water` there is money etc.)

For more detiles - [read here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/there-is-there-are/):

---

Since your sentence detailes many things, then the correct option is:

> There **are**: a theater, a cafe, and a shop near the park center.

- The fact that you use an [indefinite article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)#Indefinite_article) before each word, doesn't matter and it's the same thing as the sentence: "A goose, a horse and a cow **are** in the farm".

[image]