# Prepositions, IN/AT differences

Tags: prepositions

I wanted to have a conversation with her, so i walked to the table she was sitting **at**.

I wanted to have a conversation with her, so i walked to the table she was sitting **in**.

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [“on”, “at”, “in” as preposition of location](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54191/on-at-in-as-preposition-of-location?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't sit *in* a table, but we may sit in a *booth*:

[image]

So, either of these would be idiomatically correct:

> - I wanted to have a conversation with her, so I walked to the *table she was sitting at.*
> - I wanted to have a conversation with her, so I walked to the *booth she was sitting in.*

As a footnote, here's another way you could say it, and avoid the preposition altogether:

> - I wanted to have a conversation with her, so I walked to the *table where she was seated.*

Also, it might be worth noting that we may not sit in tables, but we do sit in chairs:

> - I wanted to have a conversation with her, so I walked to the *chair she was sitting in.*

[image]