# "Waiting me" or "waiting for me"?

Tags: prepositions, transitivity

Is it correct to say

> "My daughter will be waiting me on the Dulles Airport lobby"

or

> "My daughter will be waiting **for** me on the Dulles Airport lobby"?

Answer (score 2):

It is "*waiting **for*** me."

*Waiting me" is not standard English.

Also, the preposition *on* is not correct here. It should be [*in* or *at*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40439/should-i-say-she-is-in-the-park-or-she-is-at-the-park/40488#40488).

Comment: +1 but what if we used awaiting? Still would need the preposition *for*? I'm not sure if await me = wait for me.

Comment: @LucianSava Almost nobody says *await*. "Await is a fairly common word in formal writing, but you do not usually use it in conversation. Instead you use wait for, often followed by an object and a to-infinitive. For example, instead of saying 'I awaited her reply', you say 'I waited for her to reply'."

Comment: (The above unsourced quote is apparently from [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/awaiting), or another source that TFD uses as a source, but if so, I'm not sure which.)

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer:

It's ***wait for X***, not ****wait X***.

---

#### Longer answer:

The verb ***wait*** is usually intransitive, so it doesn't take a direct object:

> *My daughter will be **waiting me** in the Dulles Airport lobby.

This is ungrammatical.  ***Me*** is a direct object, but ***wait*** doesn't take one.

> My daughter will be **waiting for me** in the Dulles Airport lobby.

This is grammatical.  ***Wait*** takes the preposition phrase ***for me*** as a complement.

---

#### Fixed Expressions

The use of ***wait*** as a transitive verb is fairly limited:

> In our senior year Jack took a part-time job **waiting tables** in the Violet Cafe.

This is a fixed expression meaning something like "working as a waiter in a restaurant; working at a restaurant, serving customers at tables".

> Get in line and **wait your turn** like everyone else.

This is a fixed expression meaning something like "wait your turn; wait until it is your turn to do something".

Outside of fixed expressions like these, ***wait*** is typically intransitive.

---

In this answer, the * symbol marks a phrase or sentence as ungrammatical.