# Do we say "gain knowledge in school"?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

Which one is the correct preposition?
*gain knowledge in/at/through school.*

If I use the verb `acquire` instead of `gain`,which preposition is correct?

Answer (score 4):

This may be cultural. As an AmE speaker, I would say "at", but I believe BrE speakers would say "in".

Comment: What about the preposition "from"?

Comment: Not a normal usage @Cardinal

Answer (score 3):

[Prepositions are tricky](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40439/should-i-say-she-is-in-the-park-or-she-is-at-the-park/40806#comment76329_40806). When we are in school, we are also at school.

The phrase *in school* can mean *in the school building*, or *in a school program*. For example:

> I can't go to the game tomorrow; I need to be in school.
>   Tony will be in medical school next year.

The phrase *at school* usually means somewhere on the school grounds, which could be in the building, or it could mean in the parking lot.

> I was at school when I felt the earthquake.

So, you can learn *in* school, and you can learn *at* school. [**Both are used**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=learned+at+school%2Clearned+in+school&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

I wouldn't say, "I gained some knowledge through school," but I might say, "I gained that knowledge *through my schooling* (or *through my training*). That said, there's no single right way to express this; all of these can be used:

- I learned how to dance in school.
- I learned how to dance at school.
- I learned how to dance during school.
- I learned how to dance through my dance classes.
- I learned how to dance by taking it in school.

These might have slightly different nuances; for example, *I learned how to dance*:

- *in school* could mean you took a dance class
- *at school* could mean you learned it from a friend during recess
- *during school* could mean you learned it sometime between your freshman and senior year

**Bottom Line: Sometimes learners seem to convince themselves that one preposition or the other must be correct, when in fact both can sound acceptable, natural, and even idiomatic.**

Comment: The trouble for learners is that sometimes one **is** correct. The rules are so damn persnickety. Would you be just as indifferent with *I learned that in/at **{grade/middle/high/graduate}** school?*  :)

Comment: @Stoney - Yes, I understand that. too! Sometimes, the options are plentiful, and sometimes there is no wiggle room at all. The longer I mull over these questions, the more amazed I am at this confounding language.

Answer (score 1):

`I learned in school` would be the usual phrase rather than, `I gained knowledge in school` which would seem a bit off for my Canadian English that can be a hybrid of American and British at times.

`I acquired in school` is a fine sentence while `I acquired knowledge in school` may seem a bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

We

> gain knowledge **at** school
>   gain knowledge **in** school
>   gain knowledge **through** school**ing**

are all acceptable, the same with **acquire**