# Is the use of the phrase "at New York" correct?

Tags: prepositions, locative

If someone says that he lives at New York, looking at the map, is the use of the phrase "at New York" correct?

Comment: I'd say the correct form is _"to live **in**"_

Comment: @drM. "To live in" is correct regardless of "looking at the map".

Comment: Do you mean *the state of New York* or *the city of New York*? It makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean *the [state of New York](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York)*, you would almost always say ***in*** New York, because the state of New York would generally be too large to conceive of as a *point* on a map. So you would be talking about *within* (= *in*) the boundaries of the state.

The rest of my answer considers *New York* to mean *the city of New York*.

It would not be wrong to use *at*, but most native speakers would use *I live **in** New York (City)* even when looking at a map. This is because we would not conceive of living at a "point on a map" but rather as "within" (*in*) the boundaries of a city.

Details:

Regarding *in*, *at*, *on*, native speakers use ***at*** precisely when we refer to "a place or location as a point. Like an X on a map," as [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/40488/29924) mentions.

> Two drivers who are starting from different locations might refer to a map and decide to meet ***at*** New York.

Other examples of referring to cities with *at*, especially as a *point on a map*:

> The British army surrendered to the American colonists ***at*** Yorktown.
>
> The two armies fought ***at*** Bunker Hill. (not *on* Bunker Hill, which one might expect for a hill)
>
> The world's athletes gathered ***at*** London for the Olympic games.

And native speakers in the past sometimes did use *living at* such-and-such place as New York.

Here's one example from over one hundred years ago:

> They live ***at*** New York City. ([link](https://books.google.com/books?id=vEoRAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA451-IA4&dq=%22live+at+New+York%22+-city%27s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7ysWVgIvLAhUJu4MKHcnKDzEQ6AEISTAG#v=onepage&q=%22live%20at%20New%20York%22%20-city's&f=false)).

Notice the same source uses 'born ***at*** New York City', 'born ***at*** Hartford, CT', etc. But both these uses are rare nowadays.

So, the short answer to your question is that nowadays we would usually say

> I live in New York

even when looking at a map, because we do not live at points on a map. We live *within* (= *in*) the boundaries of a city.

But, if you said *at New York*, you wouldn't be wrong." You would just be referring to *New York* as a point on a map.

Comment: @theinIwin you're welcome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The speaker would say

> I live **in** New York City.

since the the city would be considered to **surround** them as they live there.

If they were pointing to a specific place on the map, they might say

> I live **at** Canal *(Street)* and Greene *(Street)*.
>   I live **at** 72nd (*Street)* and Third *(Avenue)*.

referring to the closest intersection to where they live.  This is due to the grid layout of most of the City.

Usually **street** and **avenue** are not said since the naming in unambiguous, unlike in London where

> Portland Street
>   Portland Crescent
>   Portland Gardens
>   Portland Grove
>   Portland Mews
>   Portland Place
>   Portland Rise
>   Portland Road
>   Portland Square
>   Portland Street
>   Portland Walk

are all possibilities

Answer (score -2):

You can reduce the dimension and see an area as a point when that place is far away. But not with large cities. You always say in London, in New York.