# At/In, which preposition should i use?

Tags: prepositions

I'd rather spend the vacation **in** his house watching tv with him.

I'd rather spend the vacation **at** his house watching tv with him.

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I say "She is in the park" or "She is at the park"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40439/should-i-say-she-is-in-the-park-or-she-is-at-the-park)

Comment: Someone who totally understands the answers at _Should I say "She is in the park" or "She is at the park"?_ would likely know the answer to this question too, but I don't know how a non-native speaker who has this question would find that other one and be able to tease out the way in which it applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you would use *at* - his house is a place on a map, and you want to be ***at*** that place.

> I love hanging out at Doug's place.  He has a pool, and tennis court, and a huge television.  He suggested we go to Vegas over the break, but I'd rather spend the vacation at his house watching tv.

The exception would be if you are really wanting to emphasize that you want to be indoors, as opposed to in his yard or on his patio:

> Doug asked me to come over and help him reshingle his roof. It is too hot for that sort of activity.  I'd rather spend the vacation *in* his house watching tv.

Comment: It's really context dependent though, because I'd say "I'd rather spend the vacation indoors." If I'm Siva's neighbor I can say "My husband going to be at Siva's house tomorrow" and I can also say "My husband is in Siva's house." if I'm standing in my front yard the next day and asked where my husband is.