# Get in / on a dump truck

Tags: prepositions

Which one of the sentences below is correct:

> - Have you ever gotten **in** a dump truck.
> - Have you ever gotten **on** a dump truck.

For example, I have learned that we say *in a taxi,* not *on a taxi.*

Comment: They are both correct. What are you trying to say?

Comment: Have you ever gotten into a dump truck, A-friend? Why are you asking this question?

Comment: @JimReynolds thank you very much for the concern. You are well aware about my intention. Please do me a favor and answer my question. :)

Comment: It is better if you say why you are asking, and give more information. For example, if you have 50 questions like this for school homework, we don't want to answer them here.

Comment: @J.R. I was going to know if one should say "get in" or "get on" a dump truck. Like when you say: "get in a taxi" not "on a taxi".

Comment: I made the prepositions bold; So I meant about the correct preposition. I really don't know why and who down votes my question. If you do not know why I have asked a question, ask me to explain. For me this bringing up question implies that I need to know the proper preposition. I have no idea why some people do not consider that here people like me are learning. If we were experts then why we had to ask any question.

Comment: The question is off topic because you can look  up the words *get*, *in*, and *on* a dictionary and find your answer. Which dictionaries have you consulted? What is it about the dictionary definitions that you don't understand or that you find confusing? Last, there are **many** questions here about *in, on, at*, including [this one](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40439/should-i-say-she-is-in-the-park-or-she-is-at-the-park), which has an answer with a +50 score that explains what the difference between *on* and *in* is regarding vehicles. You either get in or on a truck. Either one.

Comment: We still want more information in your questions. If you will later ask 100 questions about *in* or *on,* we won't answer them here, because it's better for you to find a book or a website that teaches you about prepositions of location.

Comment: We do say *(get/ride/sit) on a taxi* if *on* is what we mean.

Comment: It seems to me that a reasonably intelligent person can infer that an OP asking such a basic question in such a basic way is very likely asking about a common situation. What do you suppose is the ratio of people who are on taxis vs. in them at a given moment? It is not neccessarily a simple matter to look up *in* or *on* in dictionaries, which have scores of definitions for these terms, and answer the question. (Why on a bus, but in a car?) It is very arguably not a duplicate of "in the park or at the park", though it may be helpful to point someone there if it answers this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of them are correct.

If you want to say inside the front part, on the seat, then we can use *in* or *on.* They are both correct.

If you want to say inside the back part of a dump truck, we will usually say *in*, but it's also ok to say *on.*

Comment: Interesting: I wouldn't use _on_ if I was talking about getting in the cab. Maybe that's a regional thing?

Comment: @J.R. If we include the word *cab,* we use in, but for trucks, buses, planes, we use either to mean in (the cab/cabin). I'll try to add some examples to the answer if I can find them.

Comment: I don't know - if somebody were getting in the cab of a truck, I think I would only ever use *in*, never *on*.   *On* makes it sound like they're on top.  In general, I don't think one rides *on* a truck like one does for a bus or plane, because a truck is not usually a mass conveyance like a bus or plane.  Maybe it's a regional variance like J.R. says.

Comment: @stangdon - If you were driving a dump truck, and you told me, "Get on," I'd assume you'd want me to [stand up and ride in the back](http://2012books.lardbucket.org/books/regional-geography-of-the-world-globalization-people-and-places/section_08/1b85c7048d75b8c2565f59f4ef1676fd.jpg). I suppose that's possible if the dump truck is being used as a [makeshift conveyance](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_r8TnL3eN1Eo/SsTUWX-O7vI/AAAAAAAAAMc/INSaOt0qano/s320/2_734664256l.jpg) to haul people instead of dirt.