# Arrive at/in the garden

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> A: Had the flowers been watered when Sheila arrived *at the garden*?
> B: No, they were still being watered.

Am I right that it should be "in the garden" as we say

> John is in the garden.

Source: [The ILI English Series, Intermediate 2 Workbook, Page 45][1]

[image: A picture of the textbook, where the "at the garden" conversation is shown under Question 2]

Comment: Here "in the garden" is the expected construction, just as _in the garage_ is used in your example from the old ILI textbook. Did you intend to provide a link to a different lesson?

Comment: Very much related (and possibly even a duplicate): The famous [_at_ or _in_ the park question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40439/should-i-say-she-is-in-the-park-or-she-is-at-the-park). A garden is much like a smaller version of a park – you can be at it, or be in it, but _at_ includes the area around the garden's edge, while _in_ is generally more confined to within the boundaries of the garden. For the purpose of saying that someone arrived, either preposition could be used.

Comment: We almost always arrive *at* something, even if we then go *into* it, which I think was the point of the cited lesson. However, I wonder if there is a slight US vs UK issue in the point of confusion? For me (American), a garden is a discrete plot of land for cultivating plants. I would always approach it from outside, and might well stand looking at it from the edge. But I believe in the UK "garden" can refer to what I call a "yard". If that's right, then a BrE speaker could "arrive *in* the garden" by stepping out a door (though "arrived in the front/back/side garden" sounds more idiomatic).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [at](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/at)
>   1. **a.** In or near the area occupied by; in or near the location of

"Arriving *at* the garden" can be equivalent to "arriving *in* the garden", but it can also mean that Sheila has not entered the garden's limits or boundary.

Arriving *in* the garden means that Sheila is within the limits of the garden, *inside* the garden.

So both are possible. The illustration doesn't help either. If the limits of the garden include Shelia's position and extend beyond that, then *in* and *at* work. Otherwise, *in* doesn't work, but *at* does since she is near enough to the garden.

Comment: I might go so far as to say that the guy watering the garden is standing at the garden's edge, and therefore the book uses the correct preposition. But my point is you nailed this.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps. Both are grammatically correct, but with slight change of meaning.

Use of "at" suggests that the garden is viewed as a point location. Whereas using "in" would view the garden as a 2d region. If, for example I am speaking of a garden that is on the other side of town, I view the garden as the endpoint of a journey. In that case the garden is a point, and I would use "at".

In the specific example, "arrival" is a point in time, and so "at" seems appropriate. With another verb, "in" might be better. "Were the flowers being watered while Alice was walking in the garden."

The same argument could be used for other examples on that page. You can use both "at the office" and "in the office" with the same slight difference in meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The most common situation where one would arrive "at" a location would be
with something like a stadium or theater; one arrives "at" the stadium when
one reaches the ticket window, or possibly marked queueing area.  One arrives
"in" the stadium after one has gained admission and, generally, reached the
location from which one will view the event.

Perhaps the simplest way to think of arriving "at" a place is to imagine
how one would respond to "where are you?"  If one would reply "I'm on my way
to X", one isn't there yet.  If one would identify X without indicating that
one was traveling toward it (e.g. "I'm just outside X" or "I'm waiting in line for X"), one has arrived "at" the location.