# Differences between prepositions in and at

Tags: prepositions

I am with difficulty to understand this prepositions "in" and "at", specifically when it refers to places.

For example, in this sentence, which is the correct and why?

I am IN the beach.

I am AT the beach.

Comment: You can be *at* the beach or *on* the beach. The difference is explained in the answers to [Should I say "She is in the park" or "She is at the park"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40439/should-i-say-she-is-in-the-park-or-she-is-at-the-park), especially [this one](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/40488/29924).

Comment: The following link may be helpful ***At, on and in (place)*** : http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-place