# Usage of prepositions 'in' and 'at' with toponyms

Tags: prepositions

Could you clarify to me the difference between using prepositions `at` and `in` in such sentences (they are taken from some website, so they might be incorrect):

```
I arrived at Chicago on Monday.
I've never been in Denver before.
```

Thank you for your help!

Found this [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40439/should-i-say-she-is-in-the-park-or-she-is-at-the-park). Is the explanation from it by Colin Fine applicable in my case?

> Both are equally correct, and have nearly the same meaning. In would
>   mean physically within the bounds of the park, while at is slightly
>   less precise, because she might be inside the park, or perhaps just
>   outside the gates.

Comment: As you say, Colin Fine explains and illustrates the differences. However, you wouldn't say *at Chicago* or any other city. You go *to Chicago* and arrive *in Chicago*. Equally, unless you mean into the centre of Denver, you would say *I've never been to Denver before*.

Comment: @RonaldSole Presumably you mean "Equally, unless you mean into the centre of Denver, you would say _I've never been **in** Denver before_."?

Comment: @SteveES I'll try again. If someone wants to know whether you have visited a city, the question would be: *Have you been to....*  and the answer would be: *I have/haven't been to....* . It's only if the questioner wanted to know whether you had visited the central area that s/he would ask: *Have you been in....?* So, if you had only landed at London City airport, you might have been *to* London but you wouldn't have been *in* London.

Comment: "Arrived *at* Chicago" is OK. **at** refers to a point in a journey, an intermediate or final destination. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22arrived%20at%20chicago%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most native speakers would almost always use *in* rather than *at* when it comes to cities and travel:

> I arrived **in** Chicago on Monday.

One exception might be when you are talking about one particular location, such as the airport:

> I arrived at Chicago around ten o'clock, and almost missed my connecting flight.

In that case, though, the speaker is referring to the Chicago airport, more so than the city itself, so *at* can work in that context.

The confusion between *at* and *in* seems to be rather common for learners. The guidance you found in our famous "at the park" question should help, but it's unlikely to cover all situations and exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

*At* is used with points.  When you say you are *at* a place, you are saying they could find you by looking at that point on a map.  Of course knowing where something is on a map doesn't give you a lot of precise details, so you need to use *in*, etc. if you want to communicate location more precisely.

*In* is used with areas/volumes with borders, and when you are *in* a city you're saying its borders surround you.  Of course when you say *in {city}* you are being just about as precise as if you are saying *at {city}*.