# at IKEA or in IKEA?

Tags: prepositions, american-english, in-on-at

I'd like to use the phrase: "Let's buy it at IKEA!" I'm not sure if I should use "at" or "in" in that particular case. Maybe both work?
Is there any difference between them?

Comment: look at some other questions in the [in-on-at] tag. Do they help?

Comment: How would you say it?

Comment: Related: [Should I say “She is in the park” or “She is at the park”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/40439/)

Comment: @ColleenV  Unfortunately, *in* the park is different from *at* the store.  For some reason, in English, you're *in* when you're *out*, and you're *at* when you're *in*.  :)

Comment: @Andrew That's why it's "related" and not a duplicate :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

English speakers say they are *at* the store.  If they are *inside* the building, they may say they are *in* the store (but they are also *at* the store).

"At" is used for location, while "in" is (generally) used to indicate being *inside* something.

Examples:

> Q: Where did you buy your desk?
>   A: **At** Macy's.  It's sold **in** the furniture department, **on** the third floor.
>
> Q: (on the phone) Where are you?  I can't see you **in** the parking lot. Are you **at** the front of the store?
>   A: I'm **in** the store, **over by** the electronics section.
>
> Q: (texting) Where are you?
>   A:  I had to get **out** of the house, so I'm **in** the park.  I'm going **by** the coffee shop, and will be **at** your house in an hour.

Unfortunately there are many idiomatic usages.  For example, you may be ***in*** a meeting, ***at*** (or **on**) the computer, ***in*** deep contemplation, ***at*** a loss, and many others.

Answer (score 4):

*at* is usually used for a location (IKEA is a location)

*in*, if used with a location can mean inside the location/space (IKEA is also a building, with an interior space).

I would have a preference for "at" in your example, however I wouldn't necessarily say that "in" before a location is wrong. It might be OK depending on context, for example if you were already inside the building when you said it.

Also, it's quite possible to say things such as "I'll see you in IKEA", or "I was in the bank when the robbery happened", when you mean inside the building.