# "At the metro station" or "in the metro station"

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition should I use for metro station **at** or **in**?

> "I was today **at** the metro station"
>
> "I was today **in** the metro station"

As far as I know normally metro stations are mostly deep underground and I'm not sure if I'm in or at.

Comment: Also related: [**at IKEA or in IKEA**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/153540/at-ikea-or-in-ikea). The answer to this is quite simple: either one is acceptable; _at_ is especially fitting when you are around the location of the station, while _in_ is perhaps better when you are actually inside the station itself.

Comment: It's not duplicate question since the question is different. It's about a structure in which really there is a sense to be confused. It's very deep and you could be inside but it's much bigger than home that get the preposition "at" rather than "in".

Comment: That's why I included the question about IKEA as well, and clarified further in a comment. The principles are the same: neither preposition is "wrong," though one might be more fitting than the other, depending on where inside (or around) the metro station you are located. If you'd still like to see this question reopened, I suggest you edit your question carefully to summarize the differences between the two questions I've linked to and this one, so that it's evident that the other answers won't satisfactorily answer your question.