# Should I use "in" or "at" in the following sentence? "Join us at/in our Spanish patio."

Tags: prepositions

Which should I use in the next sentence?

> Join us **at/in** our Spanish patio.

Comment: "At" means "next to".  "Join us at the barbeque grill for some meat."  It is strange unless you truly meant *near* the patio rather than on it.

Comment: See [Should I say “She is in the park” or “She is at the park”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40439/should-i-say-she-is-in-the-park-or-she-is-at-the-park)

Answer (score 4):

Neither. It should actually be *on* rather than *at* or *in*. That's because we usually use the preposition *on* with things like terraces and patios because they're not completely enclosed areas like other structures with roofs and walls such as residential houses, skyscrapers, schools etc. That's why you can't be in or inside a patio or terrace the same way you can be inside an enclosed area such as a building.

*At* is probably not going to work there either since the preposition *at* when talking about places is primarily used to specify locations. You can think of locations as points on a map. You can say, for example, *"Join us at Mark's."* We don't think of Mark's as a physical space in three dimensions, but rather as the particular location where you want your friends to meet you. *Mark's* is the short form of *Mark's place*, by the way.

So, long story short, this is how you would say it:

> Join us on our Spanish patio.