# In the room vs at the room

Tags: grammar

I have been searching google and I also got some answers but they didn't satisfy me .Could someone answer it in a "native" way .

Comment: A room is a generally small enclosed space so people would say "in the room" if they are located in a room.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I say "She is in the park" or "She is at the park"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40439/should-i-say-she-is-in-the-park-or-she-is-at-the-park)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use **"in the room"** if the object, event or whatever I was specifying was actually located inside said room.

> "I think James is in the room.  I don't see him out here."

I would use **"at the room"** if the object was located outside or near the room, but not actually in it.

> "James is at the examination room.  He is going to wait for us before going inside."

Comment: We might also use _at_ for certain places in the room: _at the front of the room_, e.g.