# difference between she/he is IN and she/he is AT (a country)

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, difference

I'm confused whether I should be saying:

1. He's in Japan.
2. He's at Japan.

They both sound alright to me but I'm wondering which one is more grammatically correct.

Comment: Related question [Should I say “She is in the park” or “She is at the park”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/40439/9161)

Answer (score 4):

Only say "he's in Japan". We use 'at' for very local placement - he's at my house; she's at the front of the bus. We use 'in' for countries, cities, areas, etc. He's in Japan; he's in Tokyo; we're in London.

[At, on or in a place (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-place)