# Why can't I say "I'm on Trafalgar square" but "I'm in/at Trafalgar square". It's a surface, isn't it?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, in-on-at

Why can't I say "I'm on Trafalgar square" but "I'm in/at Trafalgar square". It's a surface, isn't it?

I've heard it from this video https://youtu.be/wGV_7az35sg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I say "She is in the park" or "She is at the park"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40439/should-i-say-she-is-in-the-park-or-she-is-at-the-park)

Comment: This link may be useful https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-place

Comment: But you ***can*** say things like [*I'm on the town square.*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+town+square&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20town%20square%3B%2Cc0) It's just that ***on*** isn't the most ***common*** preposition for that exact context, but this certainly doesn't mean it's inevitably "wrong".

Answer (score 1):

The "Square" does NOT refer to a two-dimensional shaped surface, but rather a space surrounded by buildings**. It is also a location. Thus, as per ColleenV's (link)[[Should I say "She is in the park" or "She is at the park"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40439/should-i-say-she-is-in-the-park-or-she-is-at-the-park]) indicates, in/at can be used.

If it were an actual surface such as a field or "baseball diamond"(a section of a baseball field marked with a diamond-shaped chalk outline), then you are correct, we would use "on".

*Trafalgar Square is actually a specific example of a "town square", an open space in the middle of an urban area. Traditionally, these were used as meeting places, market places, and forums, and would be the hearts of their respective communities. Confer with the Spanish/Italian "plaza"/"piazza", which only have this meaning in English.

Answer (score 0):

To add some additional information to the posted answers. I agree that you are on the grounds of Trafalgar Square. Though, not specifically "on" Trafalgar Square. The word "on" suggests that you are on something, such as being on a horse.