# In/at the end of a sentence/file

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, difference

I just realized that I don't really understand such a basic thing as whether to use "in" or "at" in contexts like:

> - Don't forget to put a period in/at the end of a sentence.
> - Don't forget to put an empty line in/at the end of a file.

"In" or "at"? And why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I say she **in** the park or she is **at** the park](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40439/should-i-say-she-is-in-the-park-or-she-is-at-the-park)

Comment: That proposed duplicate question is about the differences between "at" and "in" when referring to arbitrary *physical locations*. This question is about the correct choice of preposition before the expression "*the end of*". I didn't find anything in the answers to the other question that would help with this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*...**at** the end of...*" is always correct. The expression "*in the end*" is valid, but it never has "of" after it.

The preposition "at" has the meaning of the location of a specific point, where "in" is less specific. The end of something is a specific place, so it only makes sense to use "at". The expression "in the end" doesn't refer to a specific place, but to the outcome, or end result, generally.

This [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20end%20of%2Cat%20the%20end%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20end%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20end%20of%3B%2Cc0) shows there's a few "in the end of", but they're either non-idiomatic writing styles (like the Bible) or they're about media with titles that start, "The End of...", such as:

> *In "The End of Policing",...*"

Where "The End of Policing" is a book title.